# Paho Python MQTT client

Tags: python, mqtt, raspberry-pi2, paho, hivemq

I asked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33920600/paho-python-client-with-hivemq) last week but feel i didn't give enough information and fully explain what it is i am doing. so i am opening a new, better documented question that hopefully will be easier to understand.

I am developing a python module/library that will allow a connection to a hivemq broker with a custom version of the file authentication plugin on hivemq's website(www.hivemq.com/plugins). this plugin uses http authentication instead of the file authentication.

This python module is being used to connect a raspberry-pi2 to the hivemq broker but I am having problems with the authentication. The pi will connect in the absence of the plugin. displaying these messages from the on_log an on_message functions:

```
16 Received CONNACK (0, 0)
connected with the result code 0
```

However, as soon as I add the authentication plugin to the broker it then gives me these messages:

```
16 Received CONNACK (0, 5)
connected with the result code 5
```

to my understanding, result code 5 means refused due to not being authorised.

I also get this message from the broker:

```
ERROR- Could not get valid results from the webservice
org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: The targer server failed to respond 
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpRespoonseParser.hava:143)
```

I was told in the previous question that this was due to the broker not finding the http server. but i only get this message when the raspberry-pi connects so i dont understand why it can find with other devices but not the pi.

My code for the module is as follows:

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
#import base64

#create a client instance
client = mqtt.Client()


#The callback for when the client recieves a CONNACK response from the server
def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
   print("connected with the result code "+str(rc))
   #print("usrData: "+str(userdata))
   #print("client: " +str(client))
   #print("flags: " +str(flags))

   #Define any topics you would like the pi to
   #automatically subscribe to here

#The callback for when this client publishes to the server.
def on_publish(client, userdata, mid):
  print("message published")


#The callback for when a PUBLISH message is recieve from the server.
def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    print(msg.topic+" "+str(msg.payload))


def on_log(client, userdata, level, buf):
    print(str(level)+" "+str(buf))


#set callbacks
def setup():
    client.on_connect = on_connect
    client.on_message = on_message
    client.on_publish = on_publish
    client.on_log = on_log



#setup connection to broker
def connect(username, password):
    client.username_pw_set(username, password)
    #client.connect("mqtt.owly.uk")
    client.connect("10.19.110.73")

#publish to a topic
def publish(topic, message):
    client.publish(topic, message)


def loop():
    client.loop()
```

I think the problem is with how the paho client formats the request to the broker. i cant really think of what else it could be. i have arduinos connected to it, mqtt.fx clients connect, the only problem is with the raspberry pi.

Sorry for the lengthy question and thanks for the help in advance.

EDIT: ADDED tcpdump with packet details

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo tcpdump -nnXSs 0 port 1883
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
10:36:12.626081 IP 10.19.8.61.60353 > 52.30.179.227.1883: Flags [S], seq 1221863 198, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 227462 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], leng                                                                                        th 0
    0x0000:  4500 003c 5f98 4000 4006 e0d2 0a13 083d  E..<_.@.@......=
    0x0010:  341e b3e3 ebc1 075b 48d4 271e 0000 0000  4......[H.'.....
    0x0020:  a002 7210 fa7f 0000 0204 05b4 0402 080a  ..r.............
    0x0030:  0003 7886 0000 0000 0103 0307            ..x.........
10:36:12.638249 IP 52.30.179.227.1883 > 10.19.8.61.60353: Flags [S.], seq 104987                                                                                        220, ack 1221863199, win 17898, options [mss 8961,sackOK,TS val 1882686450 ecr 2                                                                                        27462,nop,wscale 7], length 0
    0x0000:  4500 003c 0000 4000 3106 4f6b 341e b3e3  E..<..@.1.Ok4...
    0x0010:  0a13 083d 075b ebc1 0641 fa54 48d4 271f  ...=.[...A.TH.'.
    0x0020:  a012 45ea 1a0e 0000 0204 2301 0402 080a  ..E.......#.....
    0x0030:  7037 83f2 0003 7886 0103 0307            p7....x.....
10:36:12.638365 IP 10.19.8.61.60353 > 52.30.179.227.1883: Flags [.], ack 1049872                                                                                        21, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 227464 ecr 1882686450], length 0
    0x0000:  4500 0034 5f99 4000 4006 e0d9 0a13 083d  E..4_.@.@......=
    0x0010:  341e b3e3 ebc1 075b 48d4 271f 0641 fa55  4......[H.'..A.U
    0x0020:  8010 00e5 fa77 0000 0101 080a 0003 7888  .....w........x.
    0x0030:  7037 83f2                                p7..
10:36:12.639260 IP 10.19.8.61.60353 > 52.30.179.227.1883: Flags [P.], seq 122186                                                                                        3199:1221863304, ack 104987221, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 227464 ecr 1882                                                                                        686450], length 105
    0x0000:  4500 009d 5f9a 4000 4006 e06f 0a13 083d  E..._.@.@..o...=
    0x0010:  341e b3e3 ebc1 075b 48d4 271f 0641 fa55  4......[H.'..A.U
    0x0020:  8018 00e5 fae0 0000 0101 080a 0003 7888  ..............x.
    0x0030:  7037 83f2 1067 0006 4d51 4973 6470 03c2  p7...g..MQIsdp..
    0x0040:  003c 0017 7061 686f 2f43 3844 3032 3037  .<..paho/C8D0207
    0x0050:  4432 3344 3935 4636 3437 4600 1f39 6136  D23D95F647F..9a6
    0x0060:  3632 6235 3934 6566 6632 3237 6661 6131  62b594eff227faa1
    0x0070:  6435 6365 6436 3937 3065 6665 001f 3039  d5ced6970efe..09
    0x0080:  6630 3865 3762 3432 3336 3266 6661 6435  f08e7b42362ffad5
    0x0090:  6430 6664 3237 3836 3561 6231 37         d0fd27865ab17
10:36:12.651185 IP 52.30.179.227.1883 > 10.19.8.61.60353: Flags [.], ack 1221863                                                                                        304, win 140, options [nop,nop,TS val 1882686463 ecr 227464], length 0
    0x0000:  4500 0034 79aa 4000 3106 d5c8 341e b3e3  E..4y.@.1...4...
    0x0010:  0a13 083d 075b ebc1 0641 fa55 48d4 2788  ...=.[...A.UH.'.
    0x0020:  8010 008c ab0d 0000 0101 080a 7037 83ff  ............p7..
    0x0030:  0003 7888                                ..x.
10:36:12.654912 IP 52.30.179.227.1883 > 10.19.8.61.60353: Flags [P.], seq 104987                                                                                        221:104987225, ack 1221863304, win 140, options [nop,nop,TS val 1882686467 ecr 2                                                                                        27464], length 4
    0x0000:  4500 0038 79ab 4000 3106 d5c3 341e b3e3  E..8y.@.1...4...
    0x0010:  0a13 083d 075b ebc1 0641 fa55 48d4 2788  ...=.[...A.UH.'.
    0x0020:  8018 008c 8af6 0000 0101 080a 7037 8403  ............p7..
    0x0030:  0003 7888 2002 0005                      ..x.....
10:36:12.654954 IP 10.19.8.61.60353 > 52.30.179.227.1883: Flags [.], ack 1049872                                                                                        25, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 227465 ecr 1882686467], length 0
    0x0000:  4500 0034 5f9b 4000 4006 e0d7 0a13 083d  E..4_.@.@......=
    0x0010:  341e b3e3 ebc1 075b 48d4 2788 0641 fa59  4......[H.'..A.Y
    0x0020:  8010 00e5 fa77 0000 0101 080a 0003 7889  .....w........x.
    0x0030:  7037 8403                                p7..
10:36:12.654915 IP 52.30.179.227.1883 > 10.19.8.61.60353: Flags [F.], seq 104987                                                                                        225, ack 1221863304, win 140, options [nop,nop,TS val 1882686467 ecr 227464], le                                                                                        ngth 0
    0x0000:  4500 0034 79ac 4000 3106 d5c6 341e b3e3  E..4y.@.1...4...
    0x0010:  0a13 083d 075b ebc1 0641 fa59 48d4 2788  ...=.[...A.YH.'.
    0x0020:  8011 008c ab04 0000 0101 080a 7037 8403  ............p7..
    0x0030:  0003 7888                                ..x.
10:36:12.655687 IP 10.19.8.61.60353 > 52.30.179.227.1883: Flags [F.], seq 122186                                                                                        3304, ack 104987226, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 227465 ecr 1882686467], le                                                                                        ngth 0
    0x0000:  4500 0034 5f9c 4000 4006 e0d6 0a13 083d  E..4_.@.@......=
    0x0010:  341e b3e3 ebc1 075b 48d4 2788 0641 fa5a  4......[H.'..A.Z
    0x0020:  8011 00e5 fa77 0000 0101 080a 0003 7889  .....w........x.
    0x0030:  7037 8403                                p7..
10:36:12.667605 IP 52.30.179.227.1883 > 10.19.8.61.60353: Flags [.], ack 1221863                                                                                        305, win 140, options [nop,nop,TS val 1882686480 ecr 227465], length 0
    0x0000:  4500 0034 79ad 4000 3106 d5c5 341e b3e3  E..4y.@.1...4...
    0x0010:  0a13 083d 075b ebc1 0641 fa5a 48d4 2789  ...=.[...A.ZH.'.
    0x0020:  8010 008c aaf5 0000 0101 080a 7037 8410  ............p7..
    0x0030:  0003 7889                                ..x.
^C
10 packets captured
10 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

Comment: The best way to help here would be to attach a tcpdump, so we can see what's going on (please don't use your real username / password when doing this!)

Comment: @DominikObermaier how would i go about doing this?

is it just a simple follow the instructions at:  https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pypcap  ?

this module seems to not be installing on my pi 
is there another?

Comment: Best would be to just ssh to your raspberry pi and use tcpdump from the command line. When the record starts, start the python script from another ssh session.

Comment: @DominikObermaier ive updated with a tcpdump let me know if i should add the full one instead as i dont know exactly what youre looking for and i dont think any delicate information can be exposed by me.

Comment: In order to help, I would be interested in the exact CONNECT and CONNACK messages, especially the raw bytes sent. Do you think you could upload the whole tcpdump somewhere so people can analyze it?

Comment: @DominikObermaier I have included a full tcpdump. I started the the program twice in this tcpdump so hopefully you will be able to see very clearly what parts relate to the issue

Comment: @DominikObermaier im still having trouble with this! ive changed the tcpdump to one with full packet details